# Bleach carriage return

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python bleach library to sanitize the data entered by the user on a webpage. What I am doing is get user data, clean it using bleach clean and compare if cleaned data is different than original user data, if it is then throw a warning to the user to fix it.But I am facing an issue where If a user enters some data in a text area with a carriage return bleach.clean removes \r in the original text and my comparison fails.

> For example:
>
> If user enters 
>   abc (clicks enter)
>   def
>
> When we parse the html text box we get abc\r\ndef
>
> and after bleach.clean() I am getting abc\ndef

I don't mind a carriage return in user input , but for some reason bleach is cleaning it, how do I prevent that?

Comment: alternatively, consider using `string.translate` to remove all `\r`s in the original text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre-sanitize the input before sending it to `bleach` by removing all `carriage-returns`. That should solve your problem. Here are some example use cases:

`string.translate` **Example:**

```
from string import maketrans   # Required to call maketrans function.

intab = "aeiou"
outtab = "12345"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

str = "this is string example....wow!!!"
print str.translate(trantab)
```

`string.translate` **Output:**

```
th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2....w4w!!!
```

`string.replace` **Example:**

```
str = "this is string example....wow!!! this is really string";
print str.replace("is", "was");
```

`string.replace` **Output:**

```
thwas was string example....wow!!! thwas was really string
```

**Edit:** You can also try overriding the `tags` kwarg while using `bleach.clean`

Also you can check below for more information:

- [Python docs `string.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)
- [Python docs `string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)
- [`bleach.clean` docs](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clean.html)

Comment: For something like removing a single character, `str.replace('\r', '') `is probably more readable.

Comment: @OozeMeister it's personal preference but I'll update the answer all the same thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: thanks fo the reply, but i was thinking more in terms that what about other formatting/indenting characters like \t \n etc, I will have to remove them individually and might still miss some, is there an easier way to force bleach to not sanitize them